# Cron to send email if file doesn't exist

Tags: cron, scripts, find, sendmail

I have a `cron` job that executes a shell script like following

```
00 01 * * * sh /backup/script.sh
```

Now I need to add a functionality in `cron` so that if this script doesn't exist then it generates an alert to me through email using `sendmail` utility.

Something like

```
00 01 * * * find script and execute script or if find no result then email.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two general solutions. One is to make cron notify you of the results of commands it runs. Specifically, the crontab(5) man page states that

> cron(8) will look at MAILTO if it has any reason to send mail as a
>   result of running  commands  in  ``this''  crontab.  If MAILTO is
>   defined (and non-empty), mail is sent to the user so named.

Just put a line like the following in the head of your crontab file:

```
MAILTO=username@domain.com
```

Alternatively, if you want a more specialized solution, you can create a script and put it in place where it is guaranteed to be found (like `/bin`). The script itself would check whether the actual script is present, if yes, run it, if not, send you a notification. Something along the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

myscript=/path/to/your/script
myemail=username@server.org

if [ -f "$myscript" ] ; then
    exec "$myscript"
else
    mail -s "Error running $myscript" $myemail <<EOF
There was an error running the script
$myscript
The script could not be found
EOF
fi
```

You could even make it generic:

```
#!/bin/bash

myscript=$1
shift 1
params=$*
myemail=username@server.org

if [ -f "$myscript" ] ; then
    exec "$myscript $*"
else
    mail -s "Error running $myscript" $myemail <<EOF
There was an error running the script
$myscript
The script could not be found
EOF
fi
```

Comment: You mean to say just do `crontab -e` and in the cron file having the list of crontabs just add the line `MAILTO=username@domain.com` on top of it?

Answer (score 2):

cron does this for you already. Your crontab entry says:

```
00 01 * * * sh /backup/script.sh
```

At the scheduled time, cron will execute the command you specified and email you its output.

The output of `sh /does/not/exist` is: `sh: 0: Can't open /does/not/exist`. So this is what cron will email you if the file does not exist.

You may need to make sure your system is configured correctly for email, so that cron is able to email you successfully. You mentioned sendmail; if sendmail is configured correctly, and emailing your user works, then cron will work, too.

The `MAILTO` variable can also help if you need to email a different address, or if emailing your user does not work, but emailing a specific Internet email address does. Just add the line `MAILTO=foo@example.com` above the existing line.

Comment: You mean to say to do something like `00 01 * * * sh /backup/script.sh | sendmail me@gmail.com` it will get executed and send me its output via email?

Comment: No. I mean `00 01 * * * sh /backup/script.sh` will get executed and cron will send you its output via email. That is what cron does by default: send you job output via email. cron invokes sendmail itself, without you having to do anything in addition. You only need to make sure that your system's MTA (eg. postfix, exim or sendmail) is configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you will need another script. Something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

file="/path/to/script.sh"

# if script.sh exists and is executable.
if [ -x $file ]; then
    # execute script.sh
    sh /path/to/script.sh
else 
    #send mail
    echo "script.sh doesn't exists or is not executable" | sendmail me@example.com
fi
```